# Call a function from a prototype in C++

Tags: c++

How to call a function from a prototype in c++?
Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "prototype"? And what has that to do with codeblocks (which is an IDE afaik...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see example ...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5s9345t(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: thank you i got it.. you were helpful

Comment: no problem :) happy programming

Answer (score 1):

I would rather suggest you to get an introductory C++ book from this list and read it properly :

[The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Then you'll know what you're asking. You need to study a book first, before asking such questions!

Comment: i know what i am asking.. you the one who doesn't know how to answer.. :)